# Google app script trigger based on time is not working

Tags: datatrigger

I have a google app script that copy some data from one sheet to another. I would like to set up a trigger that would launch my script each day. So I created a trigger based on time but it doesn't work. However, the script works when I do it manually.

```
function Agregation () {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    Logger.log(lr);
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Données'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('A2:E7').activate();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Classement'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('\'Données\'!A2:E7').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('A0'+(lr+1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margot, try the following code.

```
function agregation () {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Données');
  var ts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Classement');
  var lr = ts.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lr);
  ss.getRange('A2:E7').copyTo(ts.getRange('A'+(lr+1)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Apps script can activate a sheet while a user is in context but not from a trigger. I edited your code to get the sheets instead of activate them. It's executing for me now using a time-based trigger.